# How to sort a matrix by more than one column at once

Tags: tcl

I use the package struct::matrix and want to sort a matrix by two or more columns at once. Is it possible?

I read the man page of struct::matrix but I didn't get a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method (because the underlying sort method is *not* guaranteed to be stable) is to compute an extra column that contains a compound *collation key* that combines the two values, then sort on that column, and finally delete the column afterwards.

```
$m add column [lmap primary [$m get column 1] secondary [$m get column 2] {
    # There are many ways to make collation keys; here's one suitable for simple words...
    string cat $primary "," $secondary
}]
# Sort the rows by the final (new!) column
$m sort rows end
# Delete the no-longer-needed column
$m delete column end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's OK in many cases but not really elegant and it blows up the size of the matrix. I think you have to be carefull to use the comma seperator because it's ASCII-Code is greater than the ASCII-Code of an exclamation point. For the future it would be great if someone could improve struct:matrix.

Comment: @OliverScholl I was amazed that the code didn't use `lsort` internally, which uses a stable sorting algorithm (and documents that it does so) allowing you to do the two-level sort by sorting first on the secondary column and then on the primary one.